# Playwright ignores my global setup credentials

Tags: typescript, authentication, playwright

I have the following global-setup file

```
import { Browser,Page,chromium, expect } from "@playwright/test";

async function globalSetup(){
    const browser: Browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page: Page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://website/login");
    await page.getByPlaceholder('john.doe@yahoo.com').fill('john@yahoo.com');
    await page.getByPlaceholder('Password...').fill('John123');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
    await expect(page).toHaveURL("https://website/dashboard");

    await page.context().storageState({path:"./LoginAuth.json"})

    await browser.close();
}
export default globalSetup;
```

and the following test

```
import { test, expect, Page } from '@playwright/test';

test('Login to Teampulse', async ({ page }) => {

    await page.goto(" ");
    
    await expect(page).toHaveURL("https://website/dashboard");
    
});
```

The base url is defined in the config file as such

```
use: {
   
     baseURL: 'https://website/dashboard',
   
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    storageState:"./LoginAuth.json"
  },
```

Until some time ago, the test would have passed but now it fails with the following error

```
Expected string: "https://website/dashboard"
Received string: "https://website/login"
```

Note that if i access the /dashboard part of the website directly without any kind of login, it will take me to the /login page so it is behaving almost as if the global-setup part is being ignored for some reason but the odd thing is that if i misspell one of the placeholders in the global-setup file it will throw an error that it could not find the locator.

I just checked and it seems that the storageState file is empty in this case, that's why no login information is being saved. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Try to post the full `playwright.config.ts`